# R: using formattable - how to change the font

Tags: r, font-family, formattable

Just to let viewers know I am a novice at R!

I have a simple problem where I want to change the default text in the 'formattable' table to Times New Roman. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Here is my data and the 'formattable' table I've made from the data

```
sub <- read.csv('Book1.csv')

sub

   Visitor.volume                     Plant.species
1             Low               Carpodetus serratus
2                                Geranium solanderi
3                    Hebe pubescens subsp. sejuncta
4                                 Kunzea sinclairii
5                                  Kunzea toelkenii
6                             Lophomyrtus obcordata
7                                    Phormium tenax
8                                 Pimelea prostrata
9        Moderate                 Cordyline obtecta
10                            Melicytus ramiflorus 
11                           Muehlenbeckia astonii 
12                               Phormium cookianum
13           High Alectryon excelsus subsp. grandis
14                            Arthropodium cirratum
15                                         Hebe sp.
16                                 Lobelia angulata
17                     Metrosideros excelsa 'Aurea'


formattable(sub, col.names = c("Visitor volume", "Plant species"))
```

here is an image of the table output from the formattable code above:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cysz.png

Thank you!